# How to achieve multiple gcs backends in terraform

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform

Within our team. We all have our own dev project, and then we have a test and prod environment.

We are currently in the process of migrating from deployment manager, and gcloud cli. Into terraform. however we havent been able to figure out a way to create isolated backends within gcs backend. We have noticed that the remote backends support setting a dedicated workspace but we havent been able to setup something similar within gcs.

Is it possible to state that terraform resource A, will have a configurable backend, that we can adjust per project, or is the equivalent possible with workspaces?
So that we can use either tfvars, and vars parameters to switch between projects?

As stands everytime we attempt to make the backend configurable through vars, we get the error in `terraform init` of

```
Error: Variables not allowed
```

How does one go about creating isolated backends for each project.

Or if that isn't possible how can we guarantee that with multiple projects a shared backend state will not collide causing the state to be incorrect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your backend must been known when you run your `terraform init` command, I mean your backend bucket.

If you don't want to use workspace, you have to customize the backend value before running the init. We are use make to achieve this. According to the environment, make create a backend.tf file with the correct backend name. And run the init command.

---

**EDIT 1**

We have this piece of script (sh) which create the backend before triggering the terraform command. (it's our Make file that do this)

```
cat > $TF_export_dir/backend.tf << EOF
terraform {
    backend "gcs" {
        bucket = "$TF_subsidiary-$TF_environment-$TF_deployed_application_code-gcs-tfstatebackend"
        prefix = "terraform/state"
    }
}
EOF
```

Of course the bucket name pattern is dependent of our project. The `$TF_environment` is the most important because according to the env var set, the bucket reached will be different.

Comment: Ah i was worried i would have to some script to achieve this. which is a little annoying to be honest. Could u share an example of how ur make script works? 
We are tempted to attempt to use a shared project for the backend, and use workspaces. but before that I am intrigued with ur suggestion using make. If you could share it would be great.

Comment: It doesnot seems to be full answer. OP is asking for separate GCS for each GCP project. But in answer, its being said to create bucket in advance. both are separate topics. Even if you create bucket in advance, you cannot configure multiple gcs as terraform complains about "Duplicate backend configuration". OR I am missing the point here ?

Answer (score 1):

To achieve multiple or dynamic backend in gcp terraform i will give one solution, dont use any backend block and just pass this command.
`terraform init -backend-config="bucket=bucket-name" -backend-config="prefix=folder"`

It should work and you cannot add variables in backend block but passing in command line we can use variables. so it should work as dynamic.